# How to recieve email notifiaction when google sheet is NOT active for some days

Tags: google-sheets

I want to recieve email notification when google sheet is not active for more than 5 days.
Is there any script to do so or is there any easier way?

Comment: could you elaborate more on your matter?

Comment: I have several google sheets created by different users and I have to take a look when some of them are not active

Comment: What do you mean by "active"?

Comment: by no active i mean there are no changes made in lets say few days. No changes in any cell or other activities

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.